# How can I access the App Store without taking the user out of my app?

Tags: iphone, app-store

In a lot of iHandy apps, I have seen they advertise their other apps. Only when a user presses on the link, instead of being taken out of the app and into the app store, it appears a webview pops up presenting the app store. The user can then download the app with out ever leaving the app they was in.

Everything I have found on this so far, just takes me out of my app and into the native app store!

Does any one know how to present the appstore from inside an app with out having to close your app?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use StoreKit.framework if your deployment target is equals or above iOS 6.0.

```
if(NSClassFromString(@"SKStoreProductViewController")) { // Checks for iOS 6 feature.

    SKStoreProductViewController *storeController = [[SKStoreProductViewController alloc] init];
    storeController.delegate = delegate; // productViewControllerDidFinish

    // Example app_store_id
    // [NSNumber numberWithInt:647623485];

    NSDictionary *productParameters = @{ SKStoreProductParameterITunesItemIdentifier : appStoreID };

    [storeController loadProductWithParameters:productParameters completionBlock:^(BOOL result, NSError *error) {
        if (result) {
            [self presentViewController:storeController animated:YES completion:nil];
        } else {
            [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Uh oh!" message:@"There was a problem displaying the app" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil] show];
        }
    }];

} else { // Before iOS 6, we can only open the URL    
     [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:appStoreURL]
    }
}
```